# Need regular expression to remove one and only one s

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Need a regex to remove letter s

I want regex to remove s only if it is the last characte and only one instance is found

So word "boys" will become "boy"

and word "process" will remain the same since there are more than one "s" and should be case insensitive.

Please help
Thanks

---

Works only on a single word. 
I tried this code below and does not work  in a sentence.

```
string str = "The boys in the student's class didn't understand  the process.";
str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "([^s])s$", "$1");
Console.WriteLine(str);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: What output do you expect for a word like 'status'?

Comment: You don't want to use a regex. You want an inflector type library.

Comment: I using this in my Solr schemal.xml
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/analysis/PatternReplaceFilterFactory.html and want to supply the regex pattern.

it is ok if it removed word s from status too.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you need is a zero-width negative look-behind assertion;  the Perl-style regular expression would be something like this:

```
$line =~ s/(?<!s)s\b//gi;
```

Which means "remove a single 's' character if it is the last character of a word (i.e. a whitespace character is the next character) and if the preceding character is not an 's', all case insensitive."

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "The boys in the student's class didn't understand the process.";

$line =~ s/(?<!s)s\b//gi;

print "$line\n";
```

yields:  "The boy in the student' class didn't understand the process."

Comment: +1; and to avoid the `s` in `student's` to be removed, use `(?<!s)\Bs\b`.

Comment: Thanks Narthring, I should have been clear that I wanted regex to work in java language. http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/analysis/PatternReplaceFilterFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/([^s])s$/\1/
```

This in say C# is:

```
Regex.Replace(str, "([^s])s$", "$1")
```